# Riot.js router refresh

Tags: riot.js

When routing, if I am going to a route such as `riot.route('home')`, the router does as it is supposed to. It will navigate me to the URL `www.place.com/#!home`.

However, if I am already at that route, and refresh, the router will not engage when the same line of code triggers (i.e. `riot.route('home')`). What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've run `riot.router.start()` in order to fire the first event. If this doesn't help please add more details about your code and perhaps I can provider further help.